# Virsh Local vs SSH

Tags: ssh, qemu, kvm, virsh

I log in as user on a host machine and run virsh list --all and get the below:

```
Id   Name              State
----------------------------------
 13   win10             running
 14   OpenSuse          running
 -    alpinelinux3.17   shut off
```

I then ssh into the same host machine as the same user, run the command again and get the below

```
Id   Name              State
----------------------------------
-    alpinelinux3.17   shut off
-    OpenSuse          shut off
```

Please explain why this is different. Is it because when I ssh virsh is translated into virsh qemu+ssh? If so, why does that have it's own status?

I just want virsh to administer my virtual machines as user no matter how I'm accessing my host machine.